# Como realizar um SUM no Hibernate

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, query, hql

Estou tentando fazer um select via HQL porém o Java não consegue identificar o SUM gerando o seguinte erro:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.hibernate.dialect.function.StandardAnsiSqlAggregationFunctions$SumFunction.determineJdbcTypeCode(StandardAnsiSqlAggregationFunctions.java:213)
at org.hibernate.dialect.function.StandardAnsiSqlAggregationFunctions$SumFunction.getReturnType(StandardAnsiSqlAggregationFunctions.java:171)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.util.SessionFactoryHelper.findFunctionReturnType(SessionFactoryHelper.java:432)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.AggregateNode.getDataType(AggregateNode.java:85)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.SelectClause.initializeExplicitSelectClause(SelectClause.java:172)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.HqlSqlWalker.useSelectClause(HqlSqlWalker.java:924)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.HqlSqlWalker.processQuery(HqlSqlWalker.java:692)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.query(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:665)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.selectStatement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:301)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.statement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:249)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.analyze(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:278)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:206)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:158)
at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:126)
at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:88)
at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.QueryPlanCache.getHQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:167)
at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.getHQLQueryPlan(AbstractSessionImpl.java:301)
at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.createQuery(AbstractSessionImpl.java:236)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.createQuery(SessionImpl.java:1800)
at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.createQuery(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:328)
```

Porém na documentação no Hibernate como segue o link [Hibernate](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html_single/#queryhql-aggregation) diz que a função é interpretada pelo Hibernate e seu funcionamento é normal.

Porém não sei o que pode estar acontecendo de problema.

Meu código para realizar a pesquisa é o seguinte.

```
public List RotornoProduto() {

    EntityManager em = getEntityManager();

    try {

        Query q = em.createQuery("select codigo, produto, sum(quantidade) as quantidade, sum(valorTotal) as valorTotal from itens group by codigo");


        return q.getResultList();

    } finally {
        em.close();
    }

}
```

Para fins de informação utilizo banco MySQL e a aplicação é Java Desktop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para realizar um `SUM` no `Hibernate`eu fiz da seguinte forma.

consultaDAO.java

```
public List retornoMovQtdVendido(int id) {

    EntityManager em = getEntityManager();

    try {

        Query q = em.createNativeQuery("select codigo, nome, sum(quantidade) as quantidade, sum(valor) as valor from itens where codigo =" + id + " group by codigo");

        return q.getResultList();

    } finally {

        em.close();

    }

}
```

detalhaProduto.java

```
...
 List<produto> RetornaProduto = prod.retornoMovQtdVendido(1);
for (int i = 0; i < RetornaProduto .size(); i++) {

                Object[] item = RetornaProduto.toArray();
                for (Object obj : item) {
                    Object[] x = (Object[]) obj;
                    codigo = (int) x[0];
                    nome = (String) x[1];
                    quantidade = (BigDecimal) x[2];
                    valor = (BigDecimal) x[3];
                }
    ....
```

Answer (score 3):

Bom, vamos primeiro a possível causa do seu problema. Acredito que seu problema está no conjunto de atributos que você está recebendo na sua query. Você precisa de uma classe com um construtor definido para receber os parâmetros da query. Uma forma seria:

```
class ExemploQuery{
    private long codigo;
    private String produto;
    private int quantidade;
    private BigDecimal valorTotal;

    public ExemploQuery(long codigo, String produto, int quantidade, BigDecimal valorTotal) {
        this.codigo = codigo;
        this.produto = produto;
        ...
    }
    //GETTERS AND SETTERS
}
```

E a sua query ficaria da seguinte forma:

```
Query q = em.createQuery("select NEW package.ExemploQuery(codigo, produto, sum(quantidade), sum(valorTotal)) from itens group by codigo");
```

Onde o `package` será o pacote que irá conter a sua classe `ExemploQuery`.

Ainda sobre a sua pergunta, não é indicado que se nomeie métodos iniciados por letra maiúscula. E, creio eu, que o seu `finally` não possa ser atingido caso o seu método consiga atingir o `return` do mesmo. Talvez armazenar o resultado da sua query em uma lista e depois realizar o `em.close`, para então retornar o valor armazenado na sua lista seja a melhor opção.

Comment: vou tentar fazer da forma como sugeriu acima, ou coisa que citou de fazer o `em.close` após `return` e ele não entraria para executar o mesmo sim depois que ele faz o retorno ele realiza o `em.close`.